# из utf16 в utf8

Tags: ассемблер, utf-8, masm32, перекодировка, masm

Помогите пожалуйста как переделать кучу(heap) из utf16 в utf8, чтобы строка "Hello World :D" была не : `48 00 65 00|6C 00 6C 00|6F 00 20 00|57 00 6F 00|72 00 6C 00|64 00 20 00|3A 00 44 00`, а `48 65 6C 6C|6F 20 57 6F|72 6C 64 20|3A 44 00 00`

```
.486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\gdi32.inc
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\winextra.inc
 include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 

 Main   PROTO 
    .data 
        Heap dd 0
        hMylp1 dd 0
        hConsoleInput DWORD ?
        hConsoleOutput DWORD ?
    .code 

    start:  
    invoke Main 
    invoke ExitProcess,0 
    Main proc 
        invoke GetProcessHeap
        mov Heap,eax
        invoke HeapAlloc,Heap,HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,600h
        mov hMylp1,eax
        push eax
        mov [hMylp1], input()
        pop eax
        mov eax, [hMylp1]
        invoke AllocConsole
        invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
        mov hConsoleInput, EAX
        invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
        mov hConsoleOutput, EAX
        push es
        push ds
        pop es       
        mov edi,hMylp1
        mov ecx,600h 
        xor eax,eax 
        cld             
        repne scasw     
        mov eax,600h
        sub eax,ecx 
        pop es
        mov ebx, 2
        mul ebx
        invoke WriteConsoleA, hConsoleOutput, [hMylp1], eax, 0, 0
        invoke HeapFree,Heap,NULL,hMylp1   
    Main endp 
 end start
```

Попытка сделать invoke

```
.486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
  include C:\masm32\include\gdi32.inc
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\winextra.inc
 include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 

 Main   PROTO 
    .data 
        Heap dd 0
        nim dd ?
        hMylp1 dd 0
        hConsoleInput DWORD ?
        hConsoleOutput DWORD ?

    .code 

    start:  
    invoke Main 
    invoke ExitProcess,0 
    Main proc 
        invoke GetProcessHeap
        mov Heap,eax
        invoke HeapAlloc,Heap,HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,600h
        mov hMylp1,eax
        push eax
        mov [hMylp1], input()
        pop eax
        mov eax, [hMylp1]
        invoke AllocConsole
        invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
        mov hConsoleInput, EAX
        invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
        mov hConsoleOutput, EAX
        push es
        push ds
        pop es       
        mov edi,hMylp1
        mov ecx,600h 
        xor eax,eax 
        cld             
        repne scasw     
        mov eax,600h
        sub eax,ecx 
        pop es
        mov ebx, 2
        mul ebx
        mov nim, eax
        invoke WideCharToMultiByte, 1200, 0, hMylp1, eax, hMylp1, eax, NULL, NULL
        invoke WriteConsoleA, hConsoleOutput, [hMylp1], nim, 0, 0
        invoke HeapFree,Heap,NULL,hMylp1   
    Main endp 
 end start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция WideCharToMultiByte служит как раз для этих целей. Раз вы все равно WinAPI дергаете - она будет в самый раз.

Comment: Помогите сделать invoke, мне аж страшно от такого количества входных параметров https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @AlexRudenkiy а вот не надо использовать асм там, где не нужно!

Comment: ладно попыхчу ))

Comment: посмотрите почему у меня не работает invoke всё вроде бы правильно сделал :((

Comment: @AlexRudenkiy Потому что вы используете АСМ где не нужно. Этот код вполне можно написать на сях без потери в производительности.

Answer (score 0):

```
int WideCharToMultiByte(

    UINT CodePage,  // code page 
    DWORD dwFlags,  // performance and mapping flags 
    LPCWSTR lpWideCharStr,  // address of wide-character string 
    int cchWideChar,    // number of characters in string 
    LPSTR lpMultiByteStr,   // address of buffer for new string 
    int cchMultiByte,   // size of buffer 
    LPCSTR lpDefaultChar,   // address of default for unmappable characters  
    LPBOOL lpUsedDefaultChar    // address of flag set when default char. used
);
```

т.е.

```
invoke WideCharToMultiByte, 1200, 0, hMylp1, eax, hMylp1, eax, NULL, NULL
```

> invoke WideCharToMultiByte, Кодоваястраница, 0, адресИсходнойстроки, размерИсходнойстроки, БуффердляРезультирующейстроки, размерБуфферадляРезультирующейСтроки, УкарательдляНеПерекодировавшихсясимволов, NULL

Comment: Отформатировал, но всё равно ничего не ясно. Пожалуйста, объясните, что вы имели в виду?